# Sending data to php file AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have a target. It's to have a live area where you type in a username and every time you let a key go **onkeyup()** in the input area, I want it to send that data to a php file where that file will return what you just typed in and display it out where I want it. This isn't going as I like though :P. Please help, and thanks in advance.

**JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax Code**

```
function changeUsername() {
var user = $("#user").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "php/return.php",
  data: user,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $("#username-display").text(data);
  }
});
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="container" title="Press enter to submit">
<label>What is your name: </label><input type="text" name="user" required="" maxlength="200" id="user" onkeyup="changeUsername();" /> <br />
You typed: <strong id="username-display"></strong>
<strong id="msg"></strong>
</div>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$username_vuln = $_GET["user"];
$username = htmlspecialchars($username_vuln);
echo $username;
?>
```

Please let me know if you need more info to help me solve this...

Comment: echo $username, not return.

Comment: You have `function changeUsername(str)`, but are calling it without the `str` -> `onkeyup="changeUsername();"`. But you are getting the value with `var user = $('#user').val();`. So you either need to use `user` in `xhttp.open("GET", "php/return.php?user="+user, true);` **OR** change to `onkeyup="changeUsername(this.value);"`

Comment: Guys, this didn't work

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Are you checking the javascript console (if you use firefox (firebug) or chrome) it normally tells you what ajax calls were made and gives you the response. Is the response coming back correctly?

Comment: check out the ajax code I am using now. problem now is that I don't seem to be getting any feedback

Comment: In your new Ajax code you are sending just a value without a key name. Try changing `data: user,` to `data: {user:user},`.

Comment: This might sound silly, but just to make sure... Are you using a server application that supports PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo( json_encode( $username ) );
exit( 1 );
```

Comment: is this in the php file?

Comment: Guys, I tracked it down. It's an error with my Ajax script. I will update it to what I have now, but that's the error in there.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use following code

**HTML CODE**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function changeUsername() {
    // var user = $("#user").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "s.php",
      data: {'user':$("#user").val()},
      success: function(data){
         $("#username-display").text(data);

      }
    });
    }

    </script>

    <div class="container" title="Press enter to submit">
    <label>What is your name: </label><input type="text" name="user" required="" maxlength="200" id="user" onkeyup="changeUsername();" /> <br />
    You typed: <strong id="username-display"></strong>
    <strong id="msg"></strong>
    </div>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
 $username_vuln = $_GET["user"];
 $username = htmlspecialchars($username_vuln);
 echo $_GET["user"];
?>
```

Comment: You should try to explain the changes in the code so the OP knows what to look for and what was the critical change.

Comment: change this   data: user, to this  data: {'user':$("#user").val()},

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your AJAX code also change type from GET to POST in php code so, final code will be like -

```
function changeUsername() {
    var user = $("#user").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        data: {'user': user},
        type : 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#username-display").text(data);
                }
    });
}
```

PHP CODE :-

```
$username_vuln = $_POST["user"];
$username = htmlspecialchars($username_vuln);
echo json_encode($username);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Get to Post.

function changeUsername() {
var user = $("#user").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/return.php",
  data: {'user': user},
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
      alert(data);
     $("#username-display").text(data);
  }
});
}

Php code first try to get response.

$username_vuln = $_POST["user"];
```

$username = htmlspecialchars($username_vuln);
  echo $username; exit;